# How to take screenshot of your UEFI Bios?

Tags: bios, screenshot, uefi

I never really needed it, but now that I'm starting to overclock, I'm curious. I've seen people posting their actual screenshots, not pictures from camera, from their UEFI Bios.

How can I do that?

I've got an AsRock Z68 Extreme 3 Gen 3.

Comment: Unless there actually is a fancy option to do this in UEFI, this might be a duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/59500/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-my-pcs-bios At least the IP KVM approach would work here as well.

Answer (score 2):

Some UEFI setups do include a screenshot function that saves the pictures to a FAT32 USB drive that needs to be connected beforehand.

Most mainboards with this function use the <kbd>F12</kbd> key, but it may vary (consult the manual or onscreen-help).

Example on an ASUS mainboard, that also asks you which thumb drive you want to save to:

[image: Example on an ASUS mainboard]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might want to take a look at a similar question on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/290432/how-can-i-take-screenshots-of-the-pc-before-it-boots-up). I am not sure if UEFI has any advantage over BIOS on this regard but it used to not be possible under BIOS.

Footnote: As of last year(9/14/2011 ), even [Anandtech](http://www.anandtech.com/Gallery/Album/1380#5) was not above posting photos of the screen.